# Android equivalent of Cocos2D-iOS CCNode.visit() in Cocos2D-Android?

Tags: android, cocos2d-iphone, ccsprite, cocos2d-android

I have got the following code in my iOS Coco2D game:

```
CCSprite *mysprite = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"mypng.png"];
// ...Some code here... //
[mysprite visit];
```

In Coco2D Android, I write:

```
CCSprite mysprite = CCSprite.sprite("mypng.png");
// ...Some code here... //
mysprite.visit(****GL10 PARAMETER EXPECTED HERE*****);
```

What should I write as parameter in the visit method?

Comment: Please stop tagging your questions in the title, that's what the regular tags are for.

Answer (score 0):

try using

```
mysprite.visit(CCDirector.gl)
```

didn't confirm it though